# Chrome Extension: Getting Google's favicon by link[rel*='shortcut icon'] or link[rel*='icon'] not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to use:

```
document.querySelectorAll("link[rel*='icon']");
document.querySelectorAll("link[rel*='shortcut icon']");
```

but when I inspect a google page (ex: google.com) there is no `icon` or `shortcut icon`. This way works and gets the favicons for other websites.

The `shortcut icon` used to be used by Google a couple days ago. Now I'm not sure what Google is using to display their favicon.

As another question, is the `icon` and `shortcut icon` way the best way to get any website's favicon?

Comment: Try [How to get 2x favicon in Chrome extension](//stackoverflow.com/a/33349965) - N.B. you'll need `"chrome://favicon"` in manifest's "permissions".

Comment: I tried that but it's still not working. Even a couple days ago I didn't have `"chrome://favicon"` in my manifest and I was still able to change the favicon image on Google pages. I did have `"*://*/*"` in my manifest though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers will default to look for a `favicon.ico` located at the website's root if no `<link rel="icon" />` is defined. In Google case: https://www.google.com/favicon.ico

Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon to see (all?) way browser can get the favicon.